# How to call an integral types base on actual type in a cpp template?

Tags: c++, integral

How can I call an integral types base on actual type in a cpp template? For example, when the actual type is `int`, call `INT_MAX`. And when the actual type is `unsigned long`, call `ULONG_MAX`;

Of course I can just write a `if-else` statement, but is there any other way to do that? Or what's the best way to write this part of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best standard way is to rely on the `<limits>` header. A template already exists that does what you want. It's [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) with its static `max` function. So what you want will look like this:

```
auto max_int = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
```